# get full collection from mongohq using rest api

Tags: java, mongodb, get, httprequest, mongohq

I am trying to find a way to get a `collection` from `mongohq` using Java and rest API.

I know that I can get the collection on by one using Java:

```
public static String get(String collection, String id)
{
      return getString = getFromMongo("https://api.mongohq.com/databases/db/collections/"+collection+"/documents/"+id+"?_apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXX");
}

public static String getFromMongo(String url)
{
   try
   {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1)
         sb.append((char) cp);
        return sb.toString();
   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("getFromMongo: "+ e);
         return null;
    }

}
```

But I want to write a function that returns a `Set<String>` of all the documents in current collection. Anyone can help me?

I didn't find a query that does it in the [rest api documentation](http://support.mongohq.com/mongohq-api/collections.html)...

Thanks

Comment: http://support.mongohq.com/mongohq-api/documents.html

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks. I read it but I still don't know how to extract the data from it using JAVA. Can anyone help me?